# How to find the These numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Suppose  $n \in  N$. 
$n$  can be described as the sum of square of three number's.

That is $ n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ .

My Question is: How to find $a, b, c$?

Comment: If $n$ is not too large, trial and error?

Comment: $n\neq 4^m (8k+7)$ as shown on page 4 [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-704-seminar-in-algebra-and-number-theory-rational-points-on-elliptic-curves-fall-2004/projects/lugo.pdf)...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by "number" you mean nonnegative integer.

A number is the sum of two squares iff its prime factorization does not include an odd power of a prime congruent to $3 \mod 4$.

Given a number $x$ that is the sum of three squares, you can start by looking at $x-1^2, x - 2^2, \ldots$ until you find one that is the sum of two squares.

Now you just have to find those two squares...